# HP Photosmart C7200 bad margins

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. I have an *HP Photosmart C7280* printer, for which I'm using the recommended driver, "HP Photosmart c7200 Series, hpcups 3.13.3".

I'm printing on A4 paper, and in the printer properties I've selected "A4 Borderless" paper.

But when I print, the top 13mm and the bottom 30mm of the page are cut off.

I can turn on "Scale to fit" in the printer job options. In that case the whole page is printed, but scaled-down, which is not very useful.

How do I get my printer to use all of the paper? (The missing 30mm at the bottom is particularly annoying.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.

I downloaded a new driver from HP's website http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html. This solved the problem.